# Upload video to Parse platform with React Native

Tags: react-native, parse-platform, expo, react-native-ios

I have this code which allow users to chose a video from library and will return results contain video uri, duration, type, width.

what i want to do is upload this video to [Parse](https://parse.com) server, i have tried a lot of solutions but every times i get the same error

The Code To Select Video

```
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3]
    });
    if (!result.cancelled) {
        this.setState({
            image: result.uri
        });
    }
```

Results after selecting the video:

```
Object {
  "cancelled": false,
  "duration": 4716.66650390625,
  "height": 720,
  "type": "video",
  "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C925E9FC-54F4-470D-97A6-F1D72D396151/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540yousefalsbaihi%252FFUNTime_Beta/ImagePicker/74FF55E0-4653-4856-BF39-A67ECB3B560C.mov",
  "width": 1280,
}
```

Saving into Parse

```
let base64 = this.state.image
imageFile = new Parse.File("Video.mp4", base64);
imageFile.save().then(
    function() {
        posts.set("postFile", imageFile, "video/mp4");
        posts.save().then(posts => {
            Alert("DONE")
        });
    },
    function(error) {}
);
```

The error i get every times:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot create a Parse.File with that data.]
- node_modules/parse/lib/react-native/ParseFile.js:170:28 in ParseFile
* src/screens/AddPost.js:689:39 in <unknown>
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Solutions i have tried:

1. Convert the video to Base64

i tried to add "base64" to the data also didn't work 
i also tried to add "video/mp4;base64," also got the same error, even the video is converted to base 64 using this code.

```
    _videoTo64 = async videoURL => {
        const options = { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 };
        const data = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(videoURL, options);
        let vids = "base64:"+ data;
        console.log(vids);
        this.setState({
          image: vids
        });
      };
```

2. Tried to trim 'file://' from the video uri which also resulted in the same error

`image.replace("file://", "")`

even after i updated the parse save file to

`imageFile = new Parse.File("Video.mp4", this.state.image);`

I'm using [Expo](https://expo.io/) platform, image uploading is working perfectly fine after converting the image to base64, but the video is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not encoded in `base64`, so the current usage is not correct.

`Parse` will auto-detect the type of file you are uploading based on the file extension, but you can specify the `Content-Type` with a third parameter:

**Usage**

```js
imageFile = new Parse.File("Video.mp4", this.state.image, "video/quicktime");
```

**base64 Example**

```js
var base64 = "V29ya2luZyBhdCBQYXJzZSBpcyBncmVhdCE=";
var file = new Parse.File("myfile.txt", { base64: base64 });
```

Comment: Please read my question carefully i already said i tried these solutions before.

Comment: @Balalen You have not specified a type. Look at my answer.

Comment: i realized in a video, you don't have to specify file type, it will go like this: `     imageFile = new Parse.File("Video.mp4", { base64: theConvertedBase64 });
 `

Comment: @Balalen Specifying the type and encoding the base64 are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anybody came by this question i solved it like this

1. converted the video to base64
2. save the video in base64 and pass it to parse like this

```
    imageFile = new Parse.File("Video.mp4", { base64: theConvertedBase64 });
```

the solution was to put `{ base64: theConvertedBase64 }`